# SDL2 + hardware acceleration + android

Tags: android, sdl, hardware-acceleration, sdl-2

After surfing the net, i got the below information.

1) SDL is a wrapper around OpenGL.

2) Does SDL provides Hardware acceleration?
     - IT depends on Operating System.

**Question:**

1) Does SDL support hardware acceleration in Android Platform?

2) In case if it doesn't provide, what would be the best approach to attain hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 1):

SDL is a bit more than a wrapper to OpenGL. It provides low-level access to input, audio and drawing to the screen.

To answer your questions:

1. SDL 2 is officially supported on Android platform and always tries to use hardware acceleration whenever possible.
2. Use SDL 2 to set up an OpenGL context and make OpenGL draw calls.

Comment: Minor correction, SDL2 won't work at all if there's no OpenGL ES support present on Android, because it relies on it for rendering, and there's no software backend available in this platform (FWIW, I don't think there's any Android device that does not have OpenGL ES).